# inserting value from raster into overlaying point field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point, arcgis-10.3

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

I am using an etopo bathymetry map and would like to determine the depth of ~50k points in another layer.

I am sure there is a simple tool for this but I am not very familiar with rasters.

Comment: Check out this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28713/assigning-raster-value-to-point-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Spatial Analyst function [Extract Values To Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002t000000) does just that.

Comment: Yep it does just that.