# How to test if a point shapefile is in a raster in ArcMap using Python?

Tags: arcpy, raster, clip

I have a shapefile where the features are points. It should be about 500 points. All of this points are on top 5 different rasters. Some points are in one raster, but some others are not.

I need to do batch clipping, but before that, I need to test if a given point XY is in a raster A, otherwise I get an error.

Any ideas how to implement this?

I saw something similar for polygons, but I couldn't find something for points.

Comment: See if the point falls in the raster's extent.

Comment: What is the error that you get?  I would not be surprised if a search here on that did not turn up an answer to your question.  Please always include error messages in your questions.

Comment: Use extract multivalues in spatial analyst to query multiple rasters ay once

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28713/assigning-raster-value-to-point-data