# How to densify point feature class in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, point, interpolation, 3d

I have a 3D (x,y,z) single point feature class which points are equally spaced, like this:

[image]

As the distance between each points are more than one meter, I was wondering if there's a possibility to automatically identify data by adding new points like this (maybe also in arcpy):

[image]

Comment: You question is not related to lidar or point-cloud but to raster processing right ?

Comment: sorry, thats true- I just edited the title

Comment: For limited number of points. Create tin, extract time edges, create mid points, split edges by points. Create both ends points, delete spatial duplicate. Add z information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spatial Analyst extension Interpolate Tools (IDW) to create a Raster from the input point features.  Then convert back to points if that is your needed format.  Make sure to specify environment setting or specify cellSize to desired resolution (ie 1 = 1m) if you are in projected coordinate system

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

inFeats = "C:\mydata.gdb\3dpoints"
cellsize= 1
zField = "zfld"

ras = Idw(inFeats, zField, cellsize)

outfeats = "C:\mydata.gdb\3dpoints_1m"
arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(ras, Outfeats,"Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Geostatistical Analyst you can use [the Inverse Distance Weighting tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/creating-maps-using-inverse-distance-weighted-interpolation.htm) to fill in your gaps.

I think IDW is the most appropriate for your use-case of the [various interpolation tools](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-interpolation-tools.htm) available, though they do require Spatial Analyst license.

It will output a raster. Then, you can convert back to points at your desired resolution, then use [Extract Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm) to join back your z values.
See: [Assigning Raster Value to Point Data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28713/assigning-raster-value-to-point-data)

Comment: But this outputs a raster right? Do I have to use raster to point after that?

Comment: And raster to point conversions deletes my z-values

Comment: You should be able to use Extract Values to Points after the interpolation.  I will add this step to the answer...

Comment: At it's simplest level, if you have evenly-spaced points representing elevation I think IDW would simultaneously work effectively and be easiest to describe in a methods section (preventing the need to outline the statistics involved in kriging, for example).  I could be convinced otherwise which is why I provided the link to all the interpolation tools.